# Google Map API 3 rак задать отступы для fitBounds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

У меня есть карта на странице. А сбоку поверх карты лежит объект (текстовый список маркеров). Я хочу показать на карте все маркеры так, чтобы они не попадали под перекрываемую область. У Leaftlet.js есть опции в fitBounds, где я могу задавать отступы. В Google Maps API 3 у функции fitBounds недавно тоже появился второй параметр paddind, но он задает одинаковые отступы со всех сторон. А мне нужны разные отступы. Подскажите кто сталкивался, как решить подобную задачу?

Сейчас это выглядит примерно так:

```js
const points = [
{ lat:"55.795793", lng:"49.106585"},
{ lat:"55.772325", lng:"48.658927"},
{ lat:"55.903272", lng:"48.728924"}
];

const path = points.map(function (p) {
  return {lat: Number(p.lat), lng: Number(p.lng)};
});
path.push({lat: Number(points[0].lat), lng: Number(points[0].lng)});

function loadGMap () {
  const latlngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  const map = this._map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('map')[0], 
  {                    
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 55.96658,
      lng: 37.275027
    },
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
   });
   const routePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
     path: path,
     geodesic: true,
     strokeColor: '#f35048',
     strokeOpacity: 1.0,
     strokeWeight: 2
   });
   routePath.setMap(map);

   points.forEach(function (point, index) {
     const pointLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);
     const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: pointLatLng,
       label: index + '',
       map: map
    });
    latlngBounds.extend(pointLatLng);
  });
  map.setCenter( latlngBounds.getCenter(), map.fitBounds(latlngBounds));
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadGMap);
```

```css
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
  
.map__list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 40px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7);
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false'> </script>

<div class="map">
</div>
<div class="map__list">
  <p>Тут список маркеров</p>
</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, это можно сделать только через индексы или через ивенты, где клик будет передаваться на следующий элемент в списке, пока не дойдет до нужного.

Comment: @Алексей Матвеев Здравствуйте! Я сам люблю стилизованные google карты делать, правда без Leaftlet.js. Было бы отлично, если бы вы привели воспроизводимый пример вашей карты. Всего вам доброго!

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov Добавил пример в вопрос

Comment: @АлексейМатвеев Благодарю. Хочу уточнить: **1).** Нужно, что бы маркеры не перекрывались прозрачным белым фоном, где написано _«Тут список маркеров»_. Верно? **2).** Данная карта не адаптивная, т.е. маркеры не перестраиваются(например не находятся всегда в центре) при ресайзе окна браузера. Это так и задумано?